# Ler mais de uma linha com input

Tags: python, input

Estou tentando ler vários números nesse formato e guardá-los em uma lista:

```
2030706155721618
3230170874838235
4782877637240802
2406118837772520
4886405615781541
1520748465125584
1766850807841275
4886758384780627
1434406268685305
3788744200728256
```

Código:

```
l = str(input('Lista: ')
print(l)
```

Estou colando todos os números de uma vez, porém só imprime o primeiro item:

```
2030706155721618
```

Comment: Como vc está *inputando* os dados? Digita um número, ENTER, digita outro, ENTER, ou vc copiou os números (ctrl-C) e colou (ctrl-v) todos de uma vez? Pergunto porque já teve 4 respostas (uma apagada) e nenhuma resolveu, talvez porque não esteja claro como está sendo feita a entrada dos dados...

Comment: copiei todos de uma vez

Comment: porem quando executo so e imprimindo o primeiro item 2030706155721618

Comment: pretendo após imprimir todos esse elementos fazer uma lista para outros fins

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Segundo a [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input), `input` lê uma linha e a retorna como uma string ("*reads a line from input*"). E como você disse que está colando todos os números de uma vez (e eles estão um em cada linha), o `input` para de ler quando encontra uma quebra de linha e por isso só lê o primeiro.

Então uma alternativa é fazer um *loop* e ir lendo as linhas e adicionando-as na lista:

```
print('Digite os números:')
dados = [] # lista contendo os dados digitados
while True:
    linha = input()
    if linha == '': # linha vazia, interrompe o while
        break
    dados.append(linha)
```

Ou seja, mesmo se você fizer *copy-paste* dos números, tendo um em cada linha, eles serão lidos corretamente. Cada linha será lida pelo `input` e adicionada na lista.

Um detalhe é que precisamos definir alguma condição de parada. Eu fiz como sendo uma linha vazia (ou seja, se só digitar <kbd>ENTER</kbd>), então depois de colar os números, você vai ter que digitar um <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

Eu não coloquei a mensagem no `input` porque senão ela ia ser mostrada várias vezes. Mas como você está colando todos os números de uma vez, não faz sentido ver a mesma mensagem várias vezes, por isso só imprimi uma vez no início, antes do *loop*.

Uma vez tendo a lista, você pode imprimir como quiser. Por exemplo:

```
for n in dados:
    print(n)
```

Vale notar também que `input` já retorna uma string, então fazer `str(input())` é redundante e desnecessário.

---

Outra forma de ler esses números é:

```
dados = list(iter(input, ''))
```

Que faz basicamente a mesma coisa: `iter(input, '')` cria um iterador que chama `input` várias vezes, até que o valor retornado seja `''` (a string vazia). E por fim, `list` cria uma lista com os valores obtidos.

Comment: Nota aleatória: se tem algo que eu esqueço que existe no Python é que `iter` possui o parâmetro `sentinel` kkkk

Comment: @Woss Eu descobri esses dias :-)

Comment: muito obrigado.

Answer (score -1):

lo :)

Primeiro sobre sua pergunta "**input só imprimir primeiro item**"

input do english para português = "Entrada

Quando você precisar digitar algum numero para o programa fazer algum procedimento usa essa função, exemplo :

```
l = str(input('Lista: ') # o nome Lista entre aspas simples é como um titulo, o str() é um indicativo que só sera um texto.
print(l) # o print ira mostrar o que foi digitado no input
```

Se é para apresentar os números será assim:

```
lista =[
4782877637240802,
2406118837772520,
4886405615781541,
1520748465125584,
1766850807841275,
4886758384780627,
1434406268685305,
3788744200728256]

for verLista in lista:
  print(verLista)
```

[referencia input](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input)

[referencia lista](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html)

Caso não for nada disso, e ter essa sequencia de numero e todos possuem esse padrão e quantidade de numero sem a virgula e quer lista-los,Pode cortar ele de acordo com o padrão que estão sequenciados:

```
lista ="4782877637240802" # padrão
print(len(lista))
print(lista[0:len(lista)])
```

Dessa forma mesmo que todos números agrupados não terem a virgula pode manipular e recriando uma lista com todos na sequencia fatiando.

Comment: sim amigo porem quando executo l = str(input('Lista: ') e print o resultando so  e exibindo o primeiro item ou seja 2030706155721618

Comment: minha dúvida e somente porque quando executo so e me retornando o valor 2030706155721618 e não todos

Comment: na sua dúvida , pos tudo sem virgula. O que pode fazer é fatiar toda a unidade e separar eles de acordo com o padrão, tipo todos ali reparei que tem 16 posição. Tudo isso junto daria um bloco imenso que pode dividir tudo em 16 caracteres.

Comment: boa solução mais e possivel inserir os números via input e depois fazer esse procedimento?

Comment: sim , pode fatiar qualquer tipo de de dado, seja uma frase ou a sequencia de numeros :)

Answer (score -2):

Você pode tentar fazer isso:

```
lista = [2030706155721618,3230170874838235,4782877637240802,2406118837772520,4886405615781541,1520748465125584,1766850807841275,4886758384780627,1434406268685305,3788744200728256]

for n in lista:
  print(lista[n])
```

Explicação: O for é um looping, porém com um limite. Digamos que a variável "n" criada dentro do comando "for" são todos os itens da sua lista. E como o "for" tem um limite de repetições, a quantidade de itens na sua lista será o limite. E o n irá percorrer todos esses itens, e logo após isso seu print irá escrever a lista e o item que você irá escrever é o n.

Comment: Preciso inserir os Dados via Input porem ao fazer isso somente o valor 2030706155721618 e retornando sem os outros.